# Autofilter hide all rows & For each comparing issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 problems with code provided below. First off all, when I am filtering columns using autofilter function. For some configuration it is working in proper way, but when i change string in criteria parameter, sometimes all rows became hidden. No idea why it happens. Other things is issue with IF loop. I am comparing with percentage value.

So 55% can stand for 0.5512321 and so on. Like in example it is finding only values under 50%.

```
Sub code()

Dim ws As Worksheet, example As Integer, rng As Range, cl As Range

Set ws = Sheets("THAT")
With ws
    On Error Resume Next
    .ShowAllData
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="m_M"
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=""
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="m_C"

    Set rng = Range("T4", "T24000")
    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        example = cl.value
        If example <= 0.6 Then
             cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        Else
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: First, you need to fully qualify your `rng`, change to `Set rng = .Range("T4:T24000")`. Second, try using `If cl.Value2 <= 0.6 Then` , to compare the value of the cell (remove the percentage format part).

Comment: `example As Integer` - integer????

Comment: @SJR Thanks, It helps with finding proper values. Anyway, Question about hiding all rows is still open.

Comment: If you have amended your code in response to comments, please can you update. As stated, your problems seem rather vague. Or did you mean this question is now resolved?

Answer (score 0):

@SJR 
To make it clear, code 1 is working, and code 2 which looks same only autofilter critaria change and works differently. As a result in code 2 all rows become hidden, dont know why. "" stays for blanks.

```
Sub code()

Dim ws As Worksheet, example As String, rng As Range, cl As Range

Set ws = Sheets("CIP")
With ws
On Error Resume Next
.ShowAllData
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="m_M"
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=""
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="m_C"

Set rng = .Range("T4", "T34000")
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
example = cl.value2
If example <= 0.6 Then
cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Else
End If
Next cl
End With
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Second code:

```
Sub code2()

Dim ws As Worksheet, example As String, rng As Range, cl As Range

Set ws = Sheets("CIP")
With ws
On Error Resume Next
.ShowAllData
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=""
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=""
.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="m_C"

Set rng = .Range("T4", "T34000")
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
example = cl.value2
If example >= 0.6 Then
cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Else
End If
Next cl
End With
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```